# Android external keyboard custom layout, extra keys

Tags: android, layout, bluetooth, keyboard

I've been working on a .kcm file to give me my layout of choice on android. It's a rather obscure swedish dvorak version called se_sv_dvorak, http://tlundqvist.org/sv_dvorak/ .

I'm using a mac bluetooth keyboard like this: http://www.netonnet.se/ItemImages/dator/laptop/till-din-mac/mss-och-tangentbord/apple-wirelesskeyboard(160756)-Large.jpg

As you can see, this keyboard has more keys than an american keyboard, specifically the right of the ä-key, where US keyboards have apostrophe.

How can I implement this extra key?

Sincerely,
Love

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that when I hit the key in question it gave me the same character as the key to the left of Z (see picture). At first I thought this was a buggy reaction to being unbound but I soon figured out that they both were bound in the .kl file to the same keycode (D'uh)!

They were both bound to BACKSLASH for some reason. I bound one of them to HENKAN (something japanese maybe?) in the .kl file and bound HENKAN to ; and : in the .kcm file.

Everything seems to be working perfectly and I can finally start developing on my huge Xperia Z Ultra! :)

I'm sending my work to the original developer and maintainer of the layout. Maybe he will upload it to his drivers page. If someone comes here looking for this layout on android, head over to his site or send me a message!

Love and light